# Android Custom Adapter - Animation on wrong Item

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I was experimenting in Android with Custom Adapters when I stumbeld over this problem: My `MainActivity` contains a `ListView` with one `TextView` and `ImageView` per row. `ImageView` just showing a color. I have a model for my `ListView` containing a `String` for name and a `int` as a key.
My `Adapter` should set a different background color for `ImageView` for each number (key). If key is 4, `ImageView` should blink.
If I run my code first element in `List` is blinking too, but key is not 4.
Hope anybody can explain me what I am doing wrong.

```
public class myAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Test>{

    private ArrayList<Test> liste;

    public myAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Test> items) {
        super(context, resource, items);
        liste = items;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if(convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_item_main, parent, false);
        }

        Test t = getItem(position);
        TextView tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lvName);
        ImageView iv = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lvStatus);

        int k = t.getKey();
        tv.setText(t.getName());

        if (k == 1) {
            iv.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(102, 255, 51));
        }

        if (k == 2) {
            iv.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(255, 204, 51));
        }

        if (k == 3) {
           iv.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(245, 61, 0));
        }

        if (k == 4) {
            iv.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(245, 61, 0));
            final Animation animation = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0);
           animation.setDuration(1000);
            animation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
            animation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
            animation.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
            iv.startAnimation(animation);
        }


        return convertView;


    }

}

public class Test {

    private String name;
    private int key;


    public Test(String name, int key) {
        this.name = name;
        this.key = key;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public void setKey(int key) {
        this.key = key;
    }
}


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ArrayList<Test> liste = new ArrayList<>();
        liste.add(new Test("Milch", 1));
        liste.add(new Test("Käse", 2));
        liste.add(new Test("Schokolade", 3));
        liste.add(new Test("Capri Sonne", 4));

        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvShowFridge);
        myAdapter mya = new myAdapter(this, R.layout.list_view_item_main, liste);
        lv.setAdapter(mya);
    }   

}
```

Comment: Are the background colors changing like you expect them to?

Comment: yes, background colors are changing. but if i remove the color for (k == 1) i would expect that no color is set. but in my case it is setting the color for (k == 4).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that the views for items are re-used (if `convertView` is not null when passed to `getView(...)`). One particular view that was once used to display item1 may be passed in to `getView(...)` to display, let's say, item4. That means that all the properties that you set in the call for item1 are still valid - including the background and animation.

What effect does that have? Well...:

1 - if you are not specifically setting the background, it will keep the previous one (in your case, as you said, if you take out setting the background when k == 1, it will just keep the previously set color, which happened to be the one for k ==4 )

2 - you are starting the animation when you are called for k == 4, but you are not stopping it if the view is reused for any other color/index. Add a call to `iv.clearAnimation()` appropriately (for the cases when you don't need an animation).

Comment: That's it. Thank you very much :)